# localscroll.js not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

hey I was just trying to use this javascript plugin but it won't work for some reason..

html:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="menu">
     <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gigs">GIGS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#top10">TOP10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
     </div>

     <div id="content"><!-- content -->
        <div id="home">home</div>
        <div id="gigs">gigs</div>
        <div id="top10">top10</div>
        <div id="contact">contact</div>
     </div><!-- end of content -->

  </div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu').localScroll();   

});
```

you can see it live here: [www.djhighpotentials.nl](http://www.djhighpotentials.nl)